# Test Typescript unit test in debug mode using VSCode

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I would like to run the Typescript `spec.ts` in debug mode using `vs-code`.
Normally, I run it from the terminal windows as follows:

```
npm run test:unit -- page.spec.ts
```

I add `console.log` statements to identify values. Is there a way to do this in vs-code?

When this npm command is run on the terminal , I see that what is executing is a script in package.json

```
    "test:unit": "ngcc && jest --coverage --ci --config=jest.conf.json"
```

Hence, I am not clear on how to set this to run in debug mode.

All the posts I have read use `mocha` or are running the test in `browser`. These are simple unit tests which I would like to step in and step out of.

Would appreciate any tips/suggestions on this.

Comment: Is this link https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#debugging-in-vs-code something you're looking for?

Comment: It's not an easy thing to set up, but I think this link might get you going in the right direction: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
   {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": " Unit Test",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\jest\\bin\\jest.js",
        "args": [
           // "-i"
           "get-data.component.spec"
          
        ],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
    },
```